# Referencing an object outside of using() block

Tags: c#, dispose, using, idisposable, using-statement

There are many questions on this subject on SO, but I haven't found one that covers what I specifically need to understand.

One of my developers wrote this code:

```cs
//

    //  ValidationDataTable is a typed DataTable, generated by the Framework
    ValidationDataTable  validationTable;
    using (ValidationTableAdapter adapter = new ValidationTableAdapter ()) {
        using (validationTable = adapter.GetData()) { }
    }

    datafeedValidators.Add(new CountryFieldValidator(validationTable.ToDictionary(key => key.CountryCode, value => value.CountryName)));

    //  Party on...

//
```

My understanding:  The validationTable has been disposed but not garbage collected when it's referenced in the last code line – but should still have thrown an `ObjectDisposedException` on the `.ToDictionary()` call.  But this code happily builds a valid dictionary and keeps going.

I have theories, but can't find anything definitive to confirm or shoot down any of them.  And the code can be rewritten a dozen ways to avoid the issue; that's not a problem.  I just need to know what the gap in my understanding is.

My questions:

1. Is this code valid and behaving as it should?
2. If not, is the success we're seeing just a crapshoot?
3. Is there something specific about a `DataTable` that allows access after the object is disposed - similar to the way a `GZipStream` class requires you to dispose of the object to flush the stream, and therefore allows calls to `.ToArray()` and `.GetBuffer()` after the object has been disposed?
4. ... What actually causes an ObjectDisposedException to be thrown when you call methods?  I'd always assumed that was coming from the .NET framework itself.

.

**CLARIFICATION:**

This is a .NET Framework question.  The consensus is that my understanding is correct - the DataTable itself would have to throw the `ObjectDisposedException`.  Except that it doesn't.  Not anywhere in the DataTable source code - hence my asking.  I assumed that the framework would ensure an ObjectDisposedException after it had been disposed, which apparently isn't the case... unlike the GZipStream, which only allows access to two methods after Dispose(), the DataTable DGAF.  Fine.

So let me rephrase the question:  Is there anything internal to the DataTable that will bomb us because calls to a disposed table are allowed?  I can assume that Microsoft hasn't cleaned up anything internally, that all properties and values will be there, untouched, for as long as the object is in scope - that just doesn't seem like a safe assumption.  This code is going away regardless - I just wanted to understand if there was a deliberate reason Microsoft allows access to the DataTable after `Dispose()` or it was an oversight, not caring, etc.

Also, if you downvote a question or vote to close it, please leave a comment why.

Comment: 5. If this code causes team members to do a double-take and isn't easily understood (a sentiment with which I agree), then it should be changed anyway if for no other reason than supportability by the team.  And that developer should put more effort into supportability and less effort into being clever.  Entirely empty code blocks should be a red flag to anybody writing code.

Comment: Yeah, there's that.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure it's so much being clever as it is a lack of understanding on the developer's part.  Could also just be a tired mistake : P

Comment: Agreed with @David. An empty block generally means you're doing it wrong. Short answers: 1. probably, 2. probably not, 3. yes - `DataTable` does not actually *do* anything when it is disposed. It's a source of some contention, but to be clear, disposing a DataTable does nothing. 4. It's up to a specific class's implementation. Neither the framework nor the language cares about disposal. I'd advise you read up on the disposable pattern.

Comment: The `Dispose` implementation of `DataTable` is inherited from its parent class, so it doesn't necessarily do anything in `DataTable`. Classes don't always throw `ObjectDisposedException` when accessed after disposal, such as `MemoryStream`.

Comment: There is not enough information here for a good answer. It is certainly plausible that the object _could_ be safely used after being disposed, but a) disposing right after creation is silly and wrong, and b) one should not _expect_ an object to normally be usable after being disposed, unless the documentation for that object specifically calls that out (i.e. don't rely on such behavior to be preserved in the future, unless the docs say you can).

Comment: What is the inheritance tree of ValidationDataTable? is it a class you wrote? Does it inherit from DataTable?

Comment: It's a typed DataTable - so all the code is in the generated designer or .NET Framework.  I should have made that clearer, will update the question - thanks.

Comment: Given that you are unwilling to accept Eren Ersönmez's answer, this question has entered the realm of asking us to read the minds of the .Net Framework developers and should probably be closed.

Comment: Not asking anyone to read minds, wanted to know if anyone knew of a reason why.  Eren will probably get credit, though questions usually stay unmarked long enough to let others weigh in.  Unless three more people decide a question about unexpected .NET framework behavior isn't a legitimate thing to ask on SO, in which case I'll just delete the damned question and forget about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the part you're missing is the fact that "disposing" an object doesn't do anything other than what the programmer defined in the `IDisposable.Dispose` implementation. The language or the framework doesn't do anything special other than providing support for the `using` statement.

With the `using` statement, the language just provides the following: if your object implements this specific interface called `IDisposable`, then it promises to call the `Dispose` method when it exists the `using` block.  That's it.  It has no knowledge of which objects have been "disposed" or not.  It doesn't throw `ObjectDisposedException` by keeping track of disposed objects in a special way.

What throws an `ObjectDisposedException`?  Well, the programmer who implemented that `IDisposable` type would need to write a code like this somewhere in there:

```
void DoMoreWork()
{
    if(_iHaveBeenDisposedAlready) 
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(null);
    ...
```

So in your case, if the `ValidationDataTable` was implemented in a way that doesn't keep track of whether it was disposed or not, and it stores it's data in memory, then it will just work as usual. The language or the framework doesn't stop that from happening.

---

UPDATE: to answer the comments, it looks like `DataTable` doesn't directly implement `IDisposable` but it's base class (`MarshalByValueComponent`) does. They had to inherit from that base class in order to support the WinForms designer experience. Outside the design mode, `Dispose` doesn't mutate anything.  So you can safely ignore it for your normal usage. In other words, you don't need to use it within a `using` block.

Is this normal? No. Usually, `IDisposable` objects are meant to be disposed somewhere down their normal life-cycle. It surely is confusing to have an `IDisposable` that doesn't require disposing.

Comment: I clarified the code to say that `ValidationDataTable` is a typed DataTable, generated by the .NET framework.  I think I worded the problem poorly - I'm trying to figure out why the framework would allow access to DataTable members after Dispose.  Without digging through the framework source code in the DataTable inheritance hierarchy, doing so feels like golfing in a minefield.

Comment: Also, we're not keeping this code... I just wanted to understand what was going on behind the scenes with the DataTable.  Is it a case like the GZipStream, where access was allowed deliberately?  An oversight?  Or MS just not caring.

Comment: @JamesKing Looked at DataTable source code and update my answer.  It is deliberate, but if you asked MS about it, I highly doubt they'll think this is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee points out in his comment, DataTable is disposable because it inherits that from MarshalByValueComponent. It is an accident that Dispose() doesn't do anything that would cause a Disposed exception to be thrown later. Well, it's not really an *accident* per se, but there is nothing to prevent a later version of the framework to do something that *did* cause that exception.

I think it is a bad idea to count on this, and I would move the code that uses the DataTable inside the using that wraps it.

Answer (score -4):

According to the [documentation on `using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

1. Yes.  See quote below.
2. N/A
3. N/A.  If you look at [IDisposable.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) it states "Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources."  If functionality can be provided without the managed resources, then disposing an object would not be required to prevent access to that functionality.
4. The developer of the class who implemented the method or property you are accessing adds code to detect if the object is disposed and throw the exception as needed.

Also from the [documentation on `using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case, the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.

In short, `validationTable` is disposed and no longer has access to its unmanaged resources, but the managed resources (the local copy of the data) are still available.  That is assuming that `ValidationDataTable` was implemented correctly.  Since I am not finding it though google or msdn, I am assuming that it is an in house class, so anything goes.

Comment: _"validationTable is not declared and instantiated in a using statement, so it will not be disposed"_ --   This is incorrect. The `using` statement _allows_ a variable to be declared in the statement, but does not _require_ it. The referenced object will still be disposed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho That was fixed.  Also, please provide evidence to support your statements.  If I say "the sky is purple" and you say "no, the sky is green" nothing changes.